# Converting between pointers and references

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, iterator

```
std::list<Value> stdList;

stdList.push_back(Value());

Value * ptr = &stdList.back(); // <-- what will this address point to?
```

If I take the reference returned by `back()` and implicitly convert it to the less generic `Value *`, will it point to the last value of the list, or will it point to someplace unexpected?

And is there a way to create an iterator from a pointer, for use with std::list functions such as `erase()`?  I realize generic to specific (iterator to pointer) is far more feasible than going the other direction, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Comment: Note that `stdList.back()` doesn't return an iterator, it returns a reference to an element. Are you thinking of `stdList.rbegin()`?

Comment: @Xymostech - Oh, my mistake.  I asked another question a little bit ago, and one of the commenters described the return value as an iterator.  So I guess I just subconsciously picked that up.  I'll fix the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer will point to the value as it is stored inside the container.  The reference did the same thing.

You can't turn that pointer into a list iterator directly, because you've lost all the information about the surrounding structure.  To do this you would have to get clever with `list::find`.

What you are trying to do it is sometimes done using `vector`.  The reason you can turn a `vector` data element pointer into an iterator (array index) is because you know the structure of a `vector`.

Please note that `list::back()` does *not* return an iterator.  It returns a reference.  The two are quite different.  Are you thinking about `list::end()`?  Or are you genuinely confused between iterators and references?  Because you *can* get a reference from a pointer.  You do it like this:

```
Value& refval = *ptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The pointer point to the last value stored in the list.

We can not create an iterator from a pointer, iterator is a concept for the container (list here), and iterator don't care about what kind of value stored on the list.
Reference and pointer are handle for the value stored on the list, they are interchangeable, we can convert a reference to a pointer and vice versa.